# Nested for loop is time inefficient, looking for a smart alternative

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, nested

Nested for loop is very time inefficient. I have some ideas to make this efficient. Wondering if better alternatives can be shared.

I am trying to create a dataframe in python pulling values from multiple other dataframes. For a small number of variables/columns I can perform simple assignments. In the example below I want a cell each in two dataframes to be compared and make an assignment if equal. If they are not equal I need to iterate through the second dataframe till every cell is evaluated before making any assignment.

"""iterated through each row of first dataframe and then the second. This is to control for values in compared column 
are matched correctly. """

```
for i in range(len(df10)):
    for j in range(len(df6)):                 # this is not an efficient way to perform this action.
        if df10.iloc[i,0] == df6.iloc[j,1]:
            df10.iloc[i,23] = df6.iloc[j,6]
            df10.iloc[i,24] = df6.iloc[j,1]
df10.sample(n=5)
```

Comment: Look into `merge` if comparing across data frames. Please post sample data for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, please see comment for description. Leave comment if something is not clear

```py
np.random.seed(10)
df10 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(5, (5,5)))

df6 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(5, (4,6)))

display(df10)
display(df6)

## compare each pair of rows from 0th column of df10 and 1st column of df6
## using numpy broadcast. Which will return matrix of boolean with true at
## element i,j where values are equal
cond = df10.iloc[:,0].values[:,np.newaxis] == df6.iloc[:,1].values

## get matching index in array when the matrix is flatten 
indx = np.arange(cond.size)[cond.ravel()]

## convert flattened index to row and colum index (i,j)
## where i crossponds to row index in df10 and j crossponds to 
## row index in df6
i,j = indx//len(df6), indx%len(df6)

## set value using fancy indexing
df10.iloc[i,3] = df6.iloc[j,4].values
df10
```